# how to Create Setup of Web application in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, setup-project

**How to Create Web Application Set up in asp.net ?**

I have a web site in a Visual studio.I want to create a single web setup project which should install the web site.So how to create a single web setup project which supports multiple web application installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Installshield` to do that. When you go to add new project you will see that option under `Other Project Types --> Setup and Deployment`

http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio?lang=1033&ver=prem

Answer (score 0):

There are many 3rd party tools that can perform this for you (We use [Anthill](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/anthillpro/) Pro to deploy between our various environments).

I've used the full version of [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com) in the past but there was a bit of a learning curve to get it right.

The free alternative is to use the [Web Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wx3b589t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Project template in Visual Studio (This uses the 'lite' version of InstallShield I believe). You can also check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#deployment_for_web_site_projects), which describes many different options for you to deploy your website. Extract from the last link:

> Visual Studio, ASP.NET, and IIS provide tools that can help you with
>   the process of deploying your web application or web site. Some of the
>   Visual Studio tools work only with web application projects, while
>   others work only with web site projects. (All MVC projects are web
>   application projects.)

Hopefully this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483479%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should provide you a good starting point should you choose to go down the Visual Studio route.